# C# .net: How to modify a Nuget package's source code installed in my project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

So I have a Nuget package installed on my asp.net project which is outdated and help is nowhere in sight. I need to modify this nuget package's source code in order to manually put in a patch. I also need to set breakpoints and debug however VS 2015 doesn't let me step in to a code any deeper that belongs to a Nuget package.

Where is the nuget package source files on my windows 7 machine? Is there a better way of patching an old nuget package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A NuGet package typically contains an assembly so there is no source code included directly in the NuGet package.

The source code for the NuGet package would need to be provided by the package author. Most NuGet packages provide a project url to the source code if the NuGet package is open source.

If there is no project url that points to the source code then you would need to contact the package author.

Comment: The source is on github, how do I import it and use it in my project instead of the nuget package?

Comment: Compile it and use the assembly. I would just use it directly rather than trying to re-use NuGet. Unless you think your new version of the assembly would be useful to others then it might be worth publishing your own NuGet package.

Comment: @MattWard - I have modified source code of log4net nuget package. Tell me the best way to use log4net.dll produced by source code of log4net nuget package in my project?

Comment: @user299709 You can import the nuget package source code by using git. For example $ git clone source url