# Remove unnecessary NuGet references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a simple desktop app in Visual Studio 2019 Community, specifically C# .NET Core. I'm using the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` package to be able to use some functions from .NET Framework, specifically for displaying Tray Icon using Windows Forms.

It works, however, upon building, having to use that compatibility package floods the target forget with completely unrelated DLLs that definitely will not be used in the project; removing them manually from the build folder and launching the application works just like that.

I tried using Resharper to use its "Optimize references" option, however they come right back when VS is restarted, also it doesn't remove all of them.

How can I remove these redundant DLL references?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to what you're asking.

[C# .net: How to modify a Nuget package's source code installed in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780779/c-sharp-net-how-to-modify-a-nuget-packages-source-code-installed-in-my-projec)

Comment: `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` isn't actually referenced in the code, though. This is something you need to use things like `System.Drawing.Common` on .NET Core. I'm fairly sure you misunderstood my question; it's not about actual content of the code, but what NuGet leaves in build folder.